# Package structure affects managed classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, package

I have several Spring boot projects. For the purpose of this question, lets say I have the following projects with these classes:

MyProject-commons:
`cz.myproject.commons.model.MyEntity;`

MyProject-worker:
`cz.myproject.worker.repository.EntityRepository;`

`MyProject-worker` has `MyProject-commons` as a maven dependency.

`EntityRepository` is a Spring JPA repository for `MyEntity`:

```
public interface ImageMetadataRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
}
```

The problem is that I always get the following exception with this setup:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EntityRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class cz.myproject.commons.model.MyEntity
```

If I move the repository to the following package (`cz.myproject.repository.EntityRepository`), everything starts working! I am confused why the package structure affects the behavior like this.

Can someone explain what is happening and how can I make it work with the package structure I described? Thanks for any tips!

My Spring boot application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "cz.myproject.worker.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "cz.myproject.commons.model")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Spring Boot` will scan `@Entity` classes if they are placed in the same package or sub-packages where you specified the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

You have to use [@EntityScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/EntityScan.html) annotation since your `Entities` are in a different package.

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = "cz.myproject.commons.model")
```

or

`@EntityScan(basePackageClasses=MyEntity.class)` .

Instead of specifying the `basePackages` attribute , we can use `basePackageClasses`, so that the `package` where `MyEntity.java` exists will be scanned.

From the  Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/EntityScan.html) -

> `public @interface EntityScan`
>
> Configures the
>   LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean to scan for entity classes in
>   the classpath. This annotation provides an alternative to manually
>   setting
>   LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(String...)
>   and is particularly useful if you want to configure entity scanning in
>   a type-safe way, or if your LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean is
>   auto-configured. A LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean must be
>   configured within your Spring ApplicationContext in order to use
>   entity scanning. Furthermore, any existing packagesToScan setting will
>   be replaced.
>
> One of basePackageClasses(), basePackages() or its alias value() may
>   be specified to define specific packages to scan. If specific packages
>   are not defined scanning will occur from the package of the class with
>   this annotation.

Comment: I have tried putting these annotation in my main class: @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "cz.myproject.commons")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "cz.myproject.commons") but the problem prevails :(

Comment: Could you post your `@SpringBootApplication` and `@Configuration` annotated classes !

Comment: I have added the main class... I don;t have any other configuration  classes

Comment: OK. Try with this - `@EntityScan(basePackageClasses=MyEntity.class)` . Here instead of specifying the `basePackages`, we use `basePackageClasses`, so that the package where `MyEntity.java` exists will be scanned

Answer (score 0):

in META-INF folder in your resource folder make sure that you have persistance.xml in it you must have MyEntity full name as follows 
cz.myproject.commons.model.MyEntity , if you have that in the package common meta data make sure that you have the following in you application context

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="myEMF">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="YOUR_PU" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaAdapter" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
             <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

if persistance.xml in the jar then you must have classpath: before the path

if you use the class context then make sure to have the following in the entity bean creation

```
@Bean
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      em.setDataSource(dataSource());
      em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "cz.myproject.commons.model" });

      JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
      em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

      return em;
   }
```

Comment: Hi, I dont use xml configuration at all. Everything is annotation driven in my projects.